# How to solve the error Project ERROR: failed to parse default search paths from compiler output

Tags: qt5, qmake

I downloaded the QT 5.12 offline installer for mac os. Everything went well. I created a project for the desktop, the project created all the files .pro, .cpp, .h ... . The Clang compiler. I received an error during assembly.
I tried to install Qt via homebrew. I work in macOS

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: The errors need to be posted as well.